# Cosa significa "refrain" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Il 10 giugno del 1940, io e Luigi stavamo giocando in una pausa di studio. Era ancora una volta (fu l'ultima, ed era tempo, avevamo diciassette anni) il nostro gioco preferito, il **refrain** simbolico del circuito.

Alcune pagine prima nel libro si spiega in cosa consisteva il gioco del "circuito":

> Finita la ceremonia, corsi a trovare un mio amico, giocai con lui tutto il pomeriggio a un nostro gioco usuale (il «circuito», con le fiches e i bottoni a simulare i campioni del ciclismo di allora), ma che quel giorno mi parve più reale e insieme più magico del solito.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "refrain" nel primo brano. Ho letto la [definizione di questo vocabolo nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/refrain/), ma non sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "refrain" nel brano sopra citato?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Refrain](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/R/refrain.shtml):

> - (estens.) ritornello.

Sabatini Coletti

penso si riferisca ad una cosa ripetuta, fatta abitualmente, come un ritornello. 
Nel caso specifico si riferisce al solito gioco che veniva (ripetutamente) fatto tra i due amici.